# saas architecture for lamp based crm application

Tags: php, cloud, saas

This will look like range of questions but all are related to SaaS and PHP based application we have been building. We are conscious about our application architecture and studying it so that we ensure to encounter all essential techniques before we move to production and do not face any failure.!

To support SaaS we have decided to make our database multi-tenant where each customer will have its own database.  My mind is boggling around following list of questions further.

- How to provide ability to customize a SaaS multi-tenant application to suit individual tenant needs?
- How to ensure security of each tenant database so that they do not access each other's data accidently?
- What are clusters and how do we add new instances of application and database to them in case of increasing no. of customers?
- What do we do to ensure performance and scalability of SaaS website?
- How do we handle failures of SaaS application, especially when we launch new versions and updates, (continuous integration)?
- Any special solutions for handling subscribers/customers and permissions of activated and deactivated modules in SaaS application?

[I have attached block diagram of DB we have decided to go with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/micgQ.png)

Comment: This isn't a bad question, however it is pretty broad and not a good fit for this site. Stack Overflow deals with specific programming problems rather than questions of this type.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a good article with many of the items which we need to consider while developing a SaaS application in PHP. Check the [SaaS application development using PHP in Zend Framework](http://advancedphpsolutions.com/blog/zend-framework/saas-application-development-using-php-in-zend-framework/)

Answers to some of your questions are below:

*How to provide ability to customize a SaaS multi-tenant application to suit individual tenant needs?*

Its like a normal site development. Suppose you have resources A to Z then you need to keep the assigned or accessible resources of reach Tenants inside database. Then while accessing you can simply check the permissions.

*How to ensure security of each tenant database so that they do not access each other's data accidently?*

The database design on SaaS application is a topic which is discussed lots of times on Stack Overflow. You can go with Single database or unique database for each Tenants. For Big Projects the second one is suitable.

If you are going with Single Database, simply store the TENANT ID in all tables. And then while Authenticating the Tenant, keep the TENANT ID in SESSION based on the Sub Domain which the request coming from. Then pass this ID in all database operations and thus, it doesn't affect the data of any other Tenants accidentally.

Comment: This link can’t be reached